# Navigation window issues

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to create my own site and have been tinkering with the navigation bar for hours now. I can't seem to get it to look like this:

`Abdullahi Farah                         Home Blog  Contact`

This is what it currently looks like:

```
Abdullahi Farah                         
                                        contactBlogHome
```

How would I be able to keep My name and the tabs on the same lin and inside the same div with the same background Image. And also not have it cover up part of `class='intro'`

Css:

```
.nav {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-color: 000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.Menu li{
  display: inline;
  background-color: #000000;
  float:Right !important;
}

.Menu li a{
  color: #CCCCCC;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Menu li a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}


.intro {

}
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <Title>Abdullahi Farah</Title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="My Site Template.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="styling my site.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class='nav'>
      <h1 class='Name'>Abdullahi Farah</h1>
      <ul class='Menu'>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='Intro'>
      <img src="http://www.facets.la/fullview/F_2013_007_AZTEC.jpg">
      <img src="https://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/t1.0-9/10155548_10201867486469738_7586118961374075182_n.jpg">
      <p>Programmer and Designer</p>
      <p>Twitter <a href="https://twitter.com/ThaAlumniGR">#ThaAlumniGR</a></p>
      <p>Linkedin <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/abdullahi-farah/77/b19/ab3">#abdullahi-farah</a></p>
      <p>Github <a href="https://github.com/Abdullahif14688">#Abdullahif14688</a></p>
      <p>Stack Overflow <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/2890980/abdullahi-farah">#abdullahi-farah</a></p>
      <p>Coderbits <a href="https://coderbits.com/Abdullahif14688">#Abdullahif14688</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class='bio'>
      <h1 class='Welcome'>Welcome</h1>
      <h1>Bio</h1>
      <p>blah blah blah</p>
      <img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/247574_10150198699471099_3320663_n.jpg?oh=f1bd74bf2d5fdeb17ea7e778a66cf05b&oe=54409CEE&__gda__=1414378754_c42f1ccf18cdb4515fe7128488a85c4a">
      <h1>Projects</h1>
      <p>blah blah blah</p>
      <img src="http://sgaul.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/adobe-source-code-font.png">
      <h1>Products</h1>
      <p>blah blah blah</p>
      <img src="http://i1.birminghammail.co.uk/incoming/article361484.ece/alternates/s615/Apple-GooglePlay-LOGOS.jpg">
    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change html as :

```
  <div class='nav'>
 <ul class='Menu'>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></li>
      </ul>     
 <h1 class='Name'>Abdullahi Farah</h1>

    </div>
```

and  css part as:

```
.Menu
{
 display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    list-style: none outside none;
    width: 40%;
}
.Menu li{
  display: inline;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

and it shall work...:)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to float your h1 tag left and add a margin between your li's:

```
h1 {
  float:left;
}

.Menu li{
  margin-right:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change css to:

```
.Menu {
    float: right;
}

.Menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```